# Lenovo T420 keyboard power button issue

Tags: laptop, keyboard, power, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

I own a lenovo T420 and I need to power it up but the keyboard power button is shot. How could I fix this or workaround it? It is very important that I get it on.  I am using a key board from a T410. They are apparently compatible with each other. I have tried cleaning the button contact and removing the CMOS battery. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fix it by replacing the power button assembly.

Comment: I need to find a way to it without replacing anything but thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

The power button is not part of the keyboard on Lenovo machines. It is part of the bezel surrounding the keyboard. I do not know if the bezel is interchangeable with the other model, but it may not be the physical button at all. It may be an issue with the power-on circuit. You need to get it serviced.

Comment: It is the power button because other keyboards worked fine. Those other keyboards were just lent to me though.

Comment: I am now sure it is the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, since the different keyboards work fine you need to fix button / ciruitry

Comment: It could be a stuck key on the keyboard so try replacing it.

Comment: How would I find that key?

Comment: If electrically stuck, you probably cannot. You can try jiggling each key. Simpler to replace it

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there any other way to power it up without the button?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that model, but power buttons are standardized.  As long as the laptop has power, pressing the power button should turn it on.  Power buttons are just normally off momentary switches.  This means the circuit is broken, until the *moment* the switch is pressed, then it returns to the previous state.  When the power button is pressed, this allows a small current to flow from the power supply or battery to the motherboard telling it to power on.

If you need to get the laptop on *right now* simply connect a piece of wire, paperclip, etc to both end of the solder points of the power switch should turn the laptop on.  If this does not turn the laptop on, there is something else wrong, other than the switch.